# How to consume messages one by one from a kafka topic

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have built one kafka topic with a single partition.

```
kafka-topics --create --topic files.write --if-not-exists --zookeeper zookeeper:32181 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
```

It would be possible to push many messages in this topic.

But I would like a single consumer (for a given group) processes these message one by one.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: file-consumer
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          type: kafka
          brokers: localhost
          defaultBrokerPort: 29092
          defaultZkPort: 32181
          configuration:
            max.request.size: 300000
            max.message.bytes: 300000
        bindings:
          fileWriteBindingInput:
            consumer:
              autoCommitOffset: false
      bindings:
        fileWriteBindingInput:
          binder: kafka
          destination: files.write
          group: ${spring.application.name}
          contentType: 'text/plain'
```

And the Java sample code

```
@StreamListener(FileBindingProcessor.INPUT_FILE_WRITE)
public void onInputMessage(Message<String> message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT) Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {

    // I Would like here to synchronize the processing of messages one by one
    // But, If many messages are pushed to this topic (single partition), they will be processed asynchronously event if I didn't yet acknowledge the current message

    acknowledgment.acknowledge();
}
```

What is missing in my configuration?

I thought, while message is not acknowledged (offset is not increased), none other message is consumed from the same partition.

Comment: This link might be helpful for you : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/575

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this consumer config `max.poll.records` to 1 by default is 500

**max.poll.records**

> The maximum number of records returned in a single call to poll().

Comment: Thank you. But I don't see any result. Maybe configuration is not good. I have set "max.pool.records" here : spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.bindings.fileWriteBindingInput.consumer.configuration.max.poll.records: 1

Comment: `I don't see any result` what do you mean by this? this did not worked? you got the more records more than 1? @OlivierTerrien

Comment: Yes. I still consume many messages at the same time. But maybe my configuration is not good.

Comment: remove that `max.request.size` and `max.message.bytes` i try it, and also refer to @gray russell answer also

Comment: I checked by introspection and the Fetcher is stiil configured with 500. What I configured is not good. I don't know where and how setting `max.poll.records`

Comment: try this property in `configuration:` block @OlivierTerrien

Comment: I have used `ackEachRecord` in addition of `configuration.max.poll.records` and I can see now MaxPollRecords of the Fetcher set to 1. However, the behavior is not still as expected. But I guess I am not so far.

Comment: then i don't have any idea @OlivierTerrien

Comment: Thank you again. I will continue to explore this way.

Answer (score 2):

If `autoCommitOffset` is enabled (which is the default), then the binder will already acknowledge each record. So by the time, it gets to your `StreamListener`, the record is already acknowledged.

Correction:  The above statement about `StreamListener` is not quite true. The auto-ack is done when the listener exits.

Since you only have a single partition, you will get the messages in the same order as it was sent to that topic partition. 
You can disable `autoCommitOffset`, in which case, you can use manual acknowledgment.

Comment: Thank you. But in fact that is already what I did. I have disabled autoCommitOffset. I thought no more message is consumed while acknowledge is not done.

Comment: oh ok. I didn't notice that in your configuration.

Comment: `>So by the time, it gets to your `StreamListener`, the record is already acknowledged. ` - not quite true; the auto-ack is done when the listener exits - unrelated to the question, but I wanted to clear this up.

Comment: Thanks, @GaryRussell. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not acknowledging a message has nothing to do with stopping the next message from being delivered.

You cannot hand off a message to another thread and acknowledge it later; if you want single-thread processing, your must do all the processing on the listener thread.

Comment: Hi Gary. Maybe the ack method is not the good solution. Even by configuring max.poll.records to consume messages one by one I can in logs messages are consumed at the same time. For example, I push 4 messages to a single partionned topic, and I consume them by a single consumer. I can see in log all messages are consumed even if thé first one is not acked.

Comment: My need is to handle the second message only when the first had been handled. That is why I thought ack was the solution.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. From the container's perspective "handled" means the listener method exits. Acknowledging simply commits the offset on the broker, which means you won't get the message again if you restart your app. If you hand the message off to another thread for "processing", you will get the next message, regardless of consumer properties. To do what you want, you must do all the "processing" before exiting the listener method.

Comment: Sorry. Handle, consume, processe, get, all mean the same for me

Comment: How can I access to the listener from my StreamListener method ? That is the problem for me. The Framework calls this method for me. And when the method is executed, messages are already there.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean; the `@StreamListener` **is the listener**; it will only be called with one record at a time unless you increase the binding `...consumer.concurrency` and add more partitions to the topic. What do you mean by "already here" ? As @deadpool said, you can use the `max.poll.records` to reduce the actual number of pre-fetched records. Prefetching records is usually desirable to improve performance.

Comment: It works with concurrency=1. I think my main problem was caused by my reactive usage. I used subscribe() instead of block(). I published my example here : https://github.com/oterrien/kafka-stream-for-stackoverflow.
By the way, thank you for your help